# NBSP malformed while using Mojo::DOM

Tags: perl, unicode, html-entities, mojolicious

I am using Mojo::DOM Perl module to replace `<IMG>` tag, but the `&nbsp;` entity is replace by Mojo::DOM with \xa0, but when I print it out to the page the NBSP character becomes \x{fffd} and shows up as a question mark. I have tried replace \x{00a0} with &nbsp; but doing that corrupts another unicode character. Here's my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use utf8;
use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI;

my $cgi = new CGI;

print $cgi->header(-charset => 'utf-8');

my %params = $cgi->Vars;

print q[<html><head><title>UTF-8 Test</title></head><body><form method="POST"><textarea name="msg" cols="50" rows="20">].$params{msg}.q[</textarea><br/><br/><input type="submit"></form>];

if($ENV{REQUEST_METHOD} eq 'POST') {
    require Mojo::DOM;


    my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new($params{msg});

    for my $e ($dom->find('img')->each) {
          my $x = $e->attr('data-char');

          if(defined($x) && $x) {
             $e->replace($x);
          }
          else {
              $e->delete;
          }
    }

    $params{msg} = $dom->to_string();
    print '<hr/><div>'.$params{msg}.'</div>';
}

print q[</body></html>];
```

Contents of msg param that is POSTed:

> אֱלֹהִים,+אֵת+הַשָּׁמַיִם,+וְאֵת+הָאָרֶץ. 1 In the beginningpo 
>   &nbsp;<img src="p.jpg" data-char=""> Easy Bengali Typing: বাংলা টাইপ
>   করুন  Минюст РФ опубликовал список СМИ-иноагентов  Japanese Keyboard -
>   日本語のキーボード  Pre-Qin and Han (先秦兩漢)

Here's a screenshot of the output:

[image]

Comment: Where do you set the encoding for STDOUT to which `print` prints by default?

Comment: It seems odd to `print '<hr/><div>'.$params{msg}.'</div>'` when you have already closed the HTML document with `</html>`

Comment: What is in `$params{msg}` ?

Comment: @Borodin fixed & updated the question

Comment: @choroba tried that, it doesn't help, all non-ascii characters end up as junk

Comment: How did you do it?

Comment: @choroba added binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8"); to the starting of the script

Comment: Please feed just `&nbsp;` through the script.  And dump the hex of `$dom` before applying `to_string`.  I suspect that that html entity is being turned into a non-utf8 byte.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mojo::DOM expects to be working with characters, not UTF-8 encoded bytes, and so it's likely that it decodes `&nbsp;` to a character that then needs to be encoded to UTF-8 before output. The old CGI module does not decode your input parameters or encode your output like a modern framework would. So you need to handle this yourself: decode `$params{msg}` from UTF-8 before passing it to Mojo::DOM, and then encode it back to UTF-8 before putting it in the output (you are declaring an output charset of UTF-8 after all).

```
if($ENV{REQUEST_METHOD} eq 'POST') {
    require Mojo::DOM;
    require Mojo::Util;


    my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new(Mojo::Util::decode('UTF-8', $params{msg}));

    for my $e ($dom->find('img')->each) {
          my $x = $e->attr('data-char');

          if(defined($x) && $x) {
             $e->replace($x);
          }
          else {
              $e->delete;
          }
    }

    $params{msg} = Mojo::Util::encode('UTF-8', $dom->to_string());
    print '<hr/><div>'.$params{msg}.'</div>';
}
```

Comment: Why is this not accepted as the answer to the question? In a piece of code I have been struggling with that has a similar issue to the one you're describing, @Grinnz answer seems has been helpful.